# Why does Android not send my second SSL request?

Tags: android, ssl, android-emulator

My Android app is talking to a webserver using SSL and GET requests. After switching to API 10 (Gingerbread) the SSL connection works - but only for the first time after the app starts...

The first request is sent by the main activity - after getting a response, another activity starts and sends multiple requests. And none of them is answered. In both cases the request is sent using a litte WebService class that is initiated in a new AsyncTask. After downsizing this alass, the only thing it actually contains is the URL(-String). Each activity starts its own instance of this class.

Here is the method that should do the GET request. As easily visible I included some code to avoid keep-alive - not that I don't like it, but it has been suggested in other answers to do so to avoid problems with multiple connections. Well, it did not work in my case.

```
public String webGet(String methodName, Map<String, String> params) {
    String getUrl = webServiceUrl + methodName;
    index++;
    final int connectionID = index;

    int i = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (i == 0) {
            getUrl += "?";
        } else {
            getUrl += "&";
        }

        try {
            getUrl += param.getKey() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(param.getValue(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        i++;
    }

    String response;
    Log.e("WebGetURL", "["+connectionID+"] " + getUrl);
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(getUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("WebService", "Malformed URL: " + getUrl);
        return null;
    }
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    try {
        Log.e("WebGetResponse", "["+connectionID+"] openConnection()");
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        if (webServiceSsl) {
            Log.e("WebService", "Using HTTPS");
            urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } else {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        }
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false); 
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection","Keep-Alive"); 
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(false); 
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true); 
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("WebService", "I/O exception opening connection: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");

    try {
        urlConnection.connect();
        Log.e("WebGetResponse", "["+connectionID+"] getInputStream()");
        // This is the last thing I hear from my thread
        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        Log.e("WebGetResponse", "["+connectionID+"] gotInputStream()");
        byte[] contents = new byte[1024];

        int bytesRead=0;
        StringBuilder strFileContents = new StringBuilder();
        Log.e("WebGetResponse", "["+connectionID+"] Waiting for data");
        while((bytesRead = bin.read(contents)) != -1) {
            String add = new String(contents, 0, bytesRead);
            strFileContents.append(add);
        }
        bin.close();
        response = strFileContents.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("WebService", "I/O exception reading stream: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    Log.e("WebGetResponse", "["+connectionID+"] " + response);
    return response;
}
```

I have been trying ans searching - I don't get the problem. Actually I cannot test the class on a non-https server currently, so I am unaware if the problem occurs in HTTP as well. However, the handshake seems to work, because the first request works well.

And here is the code that should start the request (final param is the GET content to send):

```
    class ServerDataThread extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String[]> {

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(Integer... attempts) {
            sendActive++;
            int count = attempts.length;
            String[] responses = new String[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                responses[i] = server.webGet("collector.php", params);
            }
            return responses;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String[] responses) {
            sendActive--;
            for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
                if (responses[i] == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                onResponseData(responses[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    new ServerDataThread().execute(0);
```

Could anyone please help me out with a hint what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much!

BurninLeo

Comment: btw.: The last thing I hear (after much more than 15 seconds) is: W/System.err(3223): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
Using WireShark I could see that there actually is outgoing transmission when the method is run. So it seems that this issue is a bit more weired than I thought... The requests seems followed by a connection reset [RST] which does not look good to me.

Comment: PPS: I am currently working in the Android emulator.

Comment: PPPS: GOing a bit deeper in the network traffic give me some more clues. In the first request there is a "hello server", "hello client" followed by the SSL certificate *and* a "Client Key Exchange" request sent from the Android device followed by multiple packets. In the second and subsequent requests the SSL certificate is the last thing send from the server, Android does not send anything back until (about 90 sec. later) Android and then server tell each other to close the connection. However, I am not so deep into the Java SSL implementation to understand why no Client Key Exchange is sent.

Comment: PPPPS: (sorry for that) If becomes better every click. Could it be that I am actually suffering a performance fail on my emulator? The server closes the connection 21 seconds after the connection has been initiated. 8 seconds later my Android would send the "Client Key Exchange" package. (Wo)Man - what am I missing here right before my eyes??? Any hints? Please!

Comment: For now, here is a little workaround: Using DefaultHttpClient plus HttpGet do not provoke this error.

Comment: You've been badly advised. Setting `http.keepAlive` to `false` is a *very* bad idea with HTTPS. If you must do that, you should only do it for the current connection only, via `HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty().`

Comment: Good point, thank you!
Although I still do no know the reason for my app's misbehavior (at least in emulator), I suspect the problem in multiple requests to the same server running at the same time. Using DefaultHttpClient with only one request running works fine.